# How can I get a startIndex for each match in my RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling a bit with a RegExp result. Basically what I want to have, is a `startIndex` which gives me the exact position for each match related to the source string. So instead of an array with strings

```
var regex = /(?:\w*) from "(\w*)"/g
var result = regex.exec('import foo from "foo"');
console.log(result.slice(1)) // => ["foo"]
```

I would like to have an object something like this:

```
[{
  value: 'foo',
  startIndex: 17
}]
```

I don't think this is possible without using a special library, so my question is:

Do you know any library which returns a more precise match information or any other solution how I can solve it?

Note this is just an example RegExp. In the real application I will have more than 10 completely different RegExp. Therefore, a dynamic approach is preferred.

**Addition**

I need this for the next major version of the [GitHub Linker](https://github.com/github-linker/chrome-extension). Currently the link replacement is done with a jquery selector, which isn't that flexible and sometimes wrong. A RegExp will hopefully decrease the overhead so other developers can easily extend the [GitHub Linker](https://github.com/github-linker/chrome-extension) with other languages like Ruby, Python .... Currently just JavaScript is supported.

That's the reason why I'm looking for a solid and flexible solution.

– Thanks

Comment: @PaulRoub: I don't think it's a duplicate and what you links answers the question.

Comment: @PaulRoub The solution provided in the link would work if the string would not contain two times 'foo'. So it's not that easy to find the correct position.

Comment: @stefanbuck: I participated in that question as a commenter, and I'm sure that it's the best you can get out of JavaScript's limited API.

Comment: @stefanbuck in you case ,contain two times `foo` ,just use `lastIndexOf` instead `indexOf` function

Comment: What do you need the index for? Replacement could be done with replacement callback anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410464/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-one-string-in-another-in-javascript) seems to be close.  I've adapted it somewhat below, and it appears to get near to what was required.

```js
var str = 'import foo from "foo" import bar from "bar"'
var regex = /(?:\w*) from "(\w*)"/g;
var output = [];
while ((result = regex.exec(str))) {
  var  offset = result[0].lastIndexOf(result[1]);
  output.push('Value: ' + result[1] + ', startIndex: ' + (result.index+offset));
}

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: The OP wants the start index of the capturing group 1, not the start index of the whole match (which is returned by exec).

Comment: Mhhh ... this could work if the RegExp doesn't contain the value self at the end e.g.: 

```var str = 'import foo from "foo" foo'
var regex = /(?:\w*) from "(\w*)" foo/g;``` I'm not sure if this is a big problem in my use case ... I have to check it.

Comment: @stefanbuck you can use positive lookahead `(?:\w*) from "(\w*)" (?=\1)`