# search javascript string and get word index instead of char

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, search

I would like to search in javascript string and get all string occurrence by word index for example:

```
var str = 'Hello this is my this is world'
myFindWordIndex(str, 'this is') ==> [1, 4]
```

(two occurrences of the search string, one starts at **word** index 1 and one starts at index 4)
the solution can use JQuery

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to play with indexOf but it returns char index

Comment: could it be more complex search string like `is my this` ?

Comment: @Roi See https://jsfiddle.net/kfnrwkk0/

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest no. only simple search

Comment: What could you possibly do with the word index?

Comment: @sin I'm highlighting and manipulating the found words

Comment: How can you highlight words when you only know the word number.

Comment: @Mohammad your answer looks great, why don't you add it inline here?

Comment: @sin, i already tagged all of my words with id= (w0, w1, w2....)

Comment: Try to create an array of where the words start. Use something like this `/\b(?=\w)/`. Loop through that array testing each location for your target `this is`. The index is the word index. Or, you could do jumbo gyrations if you'd like.

Comment: @Roi Because it has problem for some word. See https://jsfiddle.net/kfnrwkk0/1/

Comment: @sln didn't exactly understand, can you formulate it?

Comment: @Mohammad, what problem does it have? (I already took it to my code)

Comment: My code return extra index, for example if you check `is` word, it return `[2, 4, 7, 9]` but right array is `[2, 5]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the phrase you're trying to find and where you're trying to find it into words. Then simply check if the phrase contains each piece of the search phrase.

```js
function check(hay, needle, from) {
  var i = 1;
  while (i < needle.length) {
    if (hay[from] != needle[i])
      return false;
    i++;
    from++;
  }
  return true;
}

function myFindWordIndex(str, findme) {
  var indices = [];
  var needle = findme.split(" ");
  var hay = str.split(" ");

  for (var i = 0; i < hay.length - needle.length; i++) {
    if (hay[i] == needle[0] && (needle.length==1||check(hay, needle, i)))
      indices.push(i);
  }
  return indices;
}
var str = 'Hello this is my this is world';

console.log(myFindWordIndex(str, 'this is')); // ==> [1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

using function from [How to find indices of all occurrences of one string in another in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410464/how-to-find-indices-of-all-occurrences-of-one-string-in-another-in-javascript) for multi search

```
function getIndicesOf(searchStr, str, caseSensitive) {
    var startIndex = 0, searchStrLen = searchStr.length;
    var index, indices = [];
    if (!caseSensitive) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();
    }
    while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
        indices.push(index);
        startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
    }
    return indices;
}

function myFindWordIndex(str, search_str) {
    var res = [];
    $.each(getIndicesOf(search_str, str, true), function(i, v) {
        res.push(str.slice(0, v).split(' ').length)
    });
    return res;
}
```

Comment: He wants multiple occurences

Comment: It's not he it's me, anyway changed it to full solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clunky solution using Lodash.js.

```
function run(str, searchingFor) {
  return _.flatten(
    _.zip(str.split(/\s+/), str.split(/\s+/))
  )
  .slice(1, -1)
  .join(' ')
  .match(/\w+\s+\w+/g)
  .reduce((a, b, i) => {
    return b === searchingFor
      ? a.concat(i)
      : a;
  }, []);
}
```

Here is it running...

```
run('Hello this is my this is world', 'this is');
// => [1, 4]
```

Not ideal. Not very portable. But it works.

Comment: It's a good answer but I prefer not to use more external packages

Answer (score 0):

adding @Mohammad's answer since it looks the cleanest:

```
var str = 'Hello this is my this is world'
var pos = myFindWordIndex(str, 'this is');
console.log(pos);

function myFindWordIndex(str, word){
    var arr = [];
    var wordLength = word.split(" ").length;
    var position = 0;
    str.split(word).slice(0, -1).forEach(function(value, i){
        position += value.trim().split(" ").length;
        position += i > 0 ? wordLength : 0;
        arr.push(position); 
    });
    return arr;
}
```