# How do I get each Index of specified word inside a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complex expression consisting of LHS, operators, RHS. In the expression, I need to place an input box in place of each RHS and append the value inside it.

So, I thought of finding the position of all the operators in the expression, and place an input box next to it. 
Her's an Example:

I have a string `var a = "(temp >= 10) && (humid >= 20) "` wherein, I need to find each position(index) of `>=` in the string expression.

I tried comparing single characters, but that is not helping me. How do I need to do this using Javascript or Jquery?

Comment: Type "javascript index of" into Google, and follow what its auto-correct suggests ...?

Comment: the *each* word make the difference here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get a single index of a substring so you have to use the famous `indexOf` method.

to get all indices you may use this trick

```
var indices = [];
var str = 'var expression = "(temp >= 10) && (humid >= 20)"'

// using a regex with the global flag
str.replace(/>=/g, function(q, index) {
  indices.push(index)
  return q;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and then use a loop to check the return value.

**From the docs**

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element
>   can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

```js
var a = 'var a = "(temp >= 10) && (humid >= 20) "';
var positions = [];
var position = -1;
while ((position = a.indexOf(">=", position + 1)) !== -1) {
    positions.push(position);
}
console.log(positions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var expression = "(temp >= 10) && (humid >= 20)";
expression = expression.split('');
expression.forEach(function(item, i){
  if(item === '>'){
    console.log('position of >: ' + i)
  }
  else if(item === '='){
    console.log('position of =: ' + i)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a regex to do a global search in the string. Like `var regex = />=/gi` Check the already existing answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3410557/8438534)

Answer (score 0):

you may refer to [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

`indexOf` will return the first index where the match is true,
try:

```
console.log(expression.indexOf('>='));
```

this will print the index of the first `'>='` occurrence.
`indexOf` can take a second argument which specifies the starting index of the search, `expression.indexOf('>=', 7);` (where 7 is the index of the first occurrence) will get the second index.