# In Angular2 How can we use textareaHighlight plugin

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating an application where I have placed a Textarea, now my requirement is 
I have a list of words and so whenever i will type anything in textarea if words matches from the available list it will be highlighted with color backgraoud , I was looking for this solution in Angular2 but won't get anything. If any one can suggest any plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [angular text input highlight](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-text-input-highlight/docs/) ?

npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-text-input-highlight

Simply reference your  with template reference variable, #textarea

```
<textarea
    mwlTextInputElement
    [(ngModel)]="text"
    #textarea>
</textarea>
```

and then pass reference into their highlight component.

```
<mwl-text-input-highlight
    [tags]="tags"
    [textInputElement]="textarea">
</mwl-text-input-highlight>
```

the Tags input take in an array of tag object, here is a function that will find the indexes, from [How to find indices of all occurrences of one string in another in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410464/how-to-find-indices-of-all-occurrences-of-one-string-in-another-in-javascript)

```
function getIndicesOf(searchStr, str, caseSensitive) {
var searchStrLen = searchStr.length;
if (searchStrLen == 0) {
    return [];
}
var startIndex = 0, index, indices = [];
if (!caseSensitive) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();
}
while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
    indices.push(index);
    startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
}
return indices;
}
```

and now to get the tag object, we can use following function, which return a list of tag object.

```
function GetTagObject(searchstr, str, caseSensitive, cssClass) {
  const startingIndices = getIndicesOf(searchstr, str, caseSensitive);

  return startingIndices.map((index) => {
     return {
    indices: {
      start: index,
      end: index + searchstr.length
    },
    cssClass: cssClass,
    data: searchstr
  }
  })
}
```

now all you need to do is to use loop (reduce) through your string array and run the function from above.

```
const text = "Stackoverflow is awesome! Perfect! awesome!";
const matchText = ["awesome", "perfect"];

const result = matchText.reduce((acc, cur) => 
  acc.concat(GetTagObject(cur, text, false, "red"))
, []);
```

Comment: I have used it and i did following Steps its showing textarea but it isn't highlighting the text. I have follow the documentation.

Comment: It is now working correctly , Can we pass an array of string in tag list so that we can highlight our predefined words , Instead of using delimiter.

Comment: looks like they require an array of tag object, which includes the tag, css class and the string itself.

updated my original answer to include a function that will get the object for you from a list of string