# get the multiple index of the same string

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I have that:

```
<div contenteditable='true' class="my_div"> mango banana jus mango <b>orange<b/></div>
```

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ^1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;^18

I want to get the index of each **mango**.

I tried that:

```
$('.my_div').keyup(function(){
   let mots = $(".my_div").html().replace(/(<[^>]*>)|(&[^;]*;)/gi, ' ').split(' ');
   mots = mots.filter( function(val){return val !== ''} );
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < mots.length; ++i) {
     if (mots[i] == "mango") {
       var indexOf_ = $(".my_div").html().indexOf(mots[i]);
       console.log(indexOf_);
     }
   }
});
```

But that code always give me '1' as index of 'mango'.
It should give me 1 and 18 as index of **mango**

Where is my error ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "index of a string in boucle for" mean?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help because your question is unclear.

Comment: @j08691 I want to get the index of 'mango', not only the first index of 'mango' but all the index of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410464/how-to-find-indices-of-all-occurrences-of-one-string-in-another-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always get 1 because you always start from the beginning of the string. The indexOf method accepts a second parameter (optional) called 'fromIndex' which indicates the index to start the search at.
So in my method below, I keep track of the last index of mango found 'lastIndexOf' and start from there the next time.

```js
$('.my_div').keyup(function(){
   let mots = $(".my_div").html().replace(/(<[^>]*>)|(&[^;]*;)/gi, ' ').split(' ');
   mots = mots.filter( function(val){return val !== ''} );
   var i;
   // Keep track of the last index
   var lastIndexOf = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < mots.length; ++i) {
     if (mots[i] == "mango") {
       // Start searching from last index +1
       lastIndexOf = $(".my_div").html().indexOf(mots[i], lastIndexOf+1);
       console.log(lastIndexOf);
     }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable='true' class="my_div"> mango banana jus mango <b>orange<b/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code -

```
$('.my_div').keyup(function(){

   var searchableString = $(".my_div").html();
   var keyword = "mango";

   var index = searchableString.indexOf(keyword);
   while (index >=0){
    console.log("Index : "+index);
    index = searchableString.indexOf(keyword, index+keyword.length)   ;
   }
 });
```