# Hangman game only matches the first character, not all of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I’m creating a Hangman game using jQuery. I seem to be having trouble with repeating letters while using `indexOf`. When I pick a correct letter it only fills in the first slot and won’t fill in the second, even if you click the same letter twice.

Example:

Name: “bob”
Typed character: “b”
Outcome: “b__”
Expected outcome: “b_b”

I tried to convert this over to using a loop, but it become an endless loop.

```
// Band Names array
var bandNames = ["AJJ", "Bob Dylan", "The Front Bottoms", "The Hotelier"];

var correctLetters = [];
var placeHolder = [];

// creates a random number between 1 and the length of the band array.
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * bandNames.length);

// picks a random band based of the length of the randomband array
var selectedBand = bandNames[randomNumber];

// add place holder based on length of band name
for (i = 0; i < selectedBand.length; i++) {
    placeHolder.push("<li></li>");
}

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var letterClicked = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

  if (selectedBand.indexOf(letterClicked) > -1) {
    // adds correct letter to the array
    correctLetters.push(letterClicked);

    placeHolder[selectedBand.indexOf(letterClicked)] = letterClicked;
    //  combines the array
    var joinArray = placeHolder.join("");

    // appand 
    $('#current-container').html("").append(joinArray);

    if (joinArray == selectedBand) {
      alert("you win");
      location.reload();
    }
  }
});
```

How can I find all the characters?

Comment: `indexOf` can have second argument, the `start` index (default is 0), so you can make for ex `let I=str.indexOf(char); while(I!=-1) {... I = str.indexOf(char, I+1) }` something like this

Comment: May I recommend the code in [this answer to the question "How to find indices of all occurrences of one string in another in JavaScript"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3410557/2694511)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon placeHolder creates an empty place holder, so you know how many letters are in the band name. The code has been updated to reflect it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexOf` will only return the first index found. What you could instead do is use `map` to `map` your `placeHolder` value to the `selectedBand` and replace all the values which match the key pressed.

Here is a working example.

```js
var bandNames = ["AJJ", "Bob Dylan", "The Front Bottoms", "The Hotelier"];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * bandNames.length);
var selectedBand = bandNames[randomNumber];

var correctLetters = [];
var placeHolder = [];

for (i = 0; i < selectedBand.length; i++) {
  selectedBand[i] === " " ? placeHolder.push(" ") : placeHolder.push("_");
}

$('#current-container').html(placeHolder);

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var letterClicked = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

  selectedBand.split("").map((letter, index) => {
    if (letter.toLowerCase() === letterClicked) {
      placeHolder[index] = selectedBand[index];
    }
  });

  $('#current-container').html(placeHolder);

  if (placeHolder.join("") == selectedBand) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert("you win");
    });
    location.reload();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="current-container">
</div>
```

**Note**: I have used `setTimeout` to display the alert because otherwise the alert displays before the last letter clicked before winning the game is displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the thing about [`String#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), it returns after the first index found. What you can do instead is to use a [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the entire string instead of just to the first match. By passing a function that interacts with the value and the index you can use a loop per letter to decide when to update the DOM.

Example usage:
Prints out each letter at each index

```js
const letters = 'ababab';

letters
  .split('') // convert to array
  forEach((letter, index) => {
    console.log("letter %s at index %i", letter, index);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a map function and get all indexes for each letter that user enter. example:

```js
const getIndexes = (letter, bandName) => bandName.split("").map((currentValue, index) => currentValue.toUpperCase() === letter.toUpperCase() ? index : undefined).filter(x => x !== undefined);
  
const indexes = getIndexes("e", "Green Day");
console.log("indexes", indexes);
```